# Do this question vs do this exercise

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which of these sentences is correct?

Can they be used alternatively?

> 1)Please do question 1
>
> 2)please do exercise 1
>
> 3)please answer question 1
>
> 4)please answer exercise 1

Answer (score 0):

**do** is a very generic verb which is understood to mean "work on" or "complete" or "apply your efforts to", so it is often used where a more specific verb could be used, *especially when the nature of the effort is clear from  context*:

For example, the boss of a painting crew could tell a worker:

> Scrape the loose paint off, sand, prime, and then paint this section of wooden fence.
>
> Do this section.

A teacher could say to her students:

> Answer the first ten questions.
>
> Do the first ten.

You can see from the first example about the fence that using **do** in lieu of more specific verbs might be a sub-optimal choice, if the worker is a new hire, say, or is inexperienced and does not know precisely what is expected of him.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use **DO** for *exercise* and **ANSWER** for the word **Question** . something like this :

1. Please answer these questions.
2. Please answer question number 2.
3. Allstudents must answer the questions individually.
4. Please do the exercises without checking the answers
5. Do exercise and raise your hand.

====================================================

---

This is the way we could use the words EXERCISE and QUESTION but the way you've written is also correct. it is not grammatically wrong.it's just a bit better to write like above.

Comment: That is my opinion too, but why?